# jQuery ajax not keeping order of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am converting a comma seperated string of ids and running each one through a simple WordPress ajax call. Like this....

**JS**

```
ids = '575,570,579';

var ids_array = ids.split(',');

ids_array.forEach(function(ids_array_item) {

    $.ajax({
        type   : 'POST',
        url    : 'myurl',
        data   : {
            action   : 'get_custom_content',
            customid : ids_array_item
        },
        success : function( response ) {

            if (response != '') {

                console.log('response : ' + response);

            }

        }

    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_custom_content', 'get_custom_content');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_custom_content', 'get_custom_content');
function get_custom_content() {

    $customid = $_POST['customid'];
    echo $customid;
    die();

}
```

I am expecting to get this back...

```
response : 575
response : 570
response : 579
```

But I get this instead...

```
response : 575
response : 579
response : 570
```

Does anybody have any idea why the order is being mangled when it is run through the ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous. Multiple HTTP requests to the same endpoint aren't guaranteed to get their responses in the same order as the requests were sent.

If order matters, then wait until all the responses are gathered (by putting the promise returned by `$.ajax` into [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) before looping over them and logging them.

Alternatively, write an HTTP endpoint that can take multiple IDs in one go and return an array of results.